# Merge 3 columns from database to 1 column in datagridview

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to merge 3 columns from my database into datagridview as one? I have Lname, Fname, and Mname in my database but i want to show it as a Fullname in my datagridview.

```
public void LoadRecords()
    {
        int i = 0;
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        cn.Open();
        cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Members", cn);
        dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            i += 1;
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(i, dr[0].ToString(), dr[1].ToString(), dr[2].ToString(), dr[3].ToString(), dr[4].ToString(), dr[5].ToString(), dr[6].ToString());
        }
        dr.Close();
        cn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: You just have to add those columns using ```+``` operator

Comment: You just need concat string like below `dataGridView1.Rows.Add(i,  .. + dr[index_Of_Fname].ToString() + dr[index_Of_Mname ].ToString() + dr[index_Of_Lname].ToString() );`

Comment: Learn How to concatenate multiple strings:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/concatenate-multiple-strings

Comment: Thank you, i'll try to learn how it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need concat string like below

```
var fullName = dr[index_Of_Fname].ToString() + ", " + dr[index_Of_Mname ].ToString() + " " + dr[index_Of_Lname].ToString();
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(i,  .., fullName,..);
```

Comment: This works for me but how can I add a punctuation and a space so it will look like Doe, John A. Instead of DoeJohnA?

Comment: concat with space as you wish. I've updated my answer, please take a look at.

Answer (score 1):

You can query it as a single field.

```
"SELECT Fname + ' ' + MName + ' ' + LName as [Name], column2,column3 FROM Members"
```

Comment: Hello, I also have other columns in datagridview such as Gender, Address, etc. Is it possible to just add another query for the other fields?

Comment: @heejin, You can specify the required columns in the the same select query.

Comment: it was giving me an error when i tried to specify the other column in the select query

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void LoadRecords(){
    int i = 0;
    dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
    cn.Open();
    cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Members", cn);
    DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
    tbl.Load(cm.ExecuteReader());
    string fullName = tbl.Rows[0][1].ToString() + tbl.Rows[0][2].ToString();
    // 0 points to first row and for example full name exists in second and third column then you can add fullName to dataGridView as one
    dr.Close();
    cn.Close();
}
```